# powershell script to disconnect same user name connection

Tags: powershell, vpn

New to powershell here.

We use Microsoft routing and remote access for VPN. We have been trying to make a script that will run every 15 minutes to check the VPN and disconnect clients that are logged in twice.

Any script this to disconnect the duplicate connection with the shortest time?

Any help will do

Thanks

Comment: Please review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide some effort of coding the solution. SO is for helping out people who are stuck on a specific coding issue. You could start by looking here [Remote Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/remoteaccess/?view=win10-ps) for different commands that may be available to you. Maybe a combination of `Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics` and `Disconnect-VPNUser` will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

This section gets a list of connected clients to the VPN server, than it proceeds to group that list and count the client that appears more than on time, than it disconnects the duplicated clients.

```
#Check for duplicated connections
$Hosts = Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName | Group-Object | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1}
Foreach ($dupConnection in $Hosts){
    $ConnectionsCount = $dupConnection.Count
    $hostToDisconnect = $dupConnection.Name
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black "Dropped host $hostToDisconnect it had duplicated connections.( $ConnectionsCount connections) "
    Disconnect-VpnUser -UserName $hostToDisconnect
}
```

This section checks if the client responds to ping, if does not, it disconnects the client as well.

```
#Check if client responds to ping
$hoststoping = Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
foreach ($Client in $hoststoping){
  if (Test-Connection -computername $Client -Count 1 -quiet){
    Write-Host "$Client is responding"
  }
  else{
    Write-Host "$Client is down"
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Black "dropped host $Client dead connection."
    #Disconnect-VpnUser -UserName $Client
  }
}
```